# how to import web sessions recorded using fiddler in to jmeter?

Tags: export, jmeter, fiddler, recording

I use fiddler to record a web session. I export the recorded sessions into various formats like Curl Script, WCAT Script, Meddler Script, Html5 script, visualStudio web test.
How to import the recorded session into jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter appears to only support a proprietary XML format called **jmeterTestPlan**. While it would probably be possible to develop a Fiddler exporter that would save to that format, it's not clear that it would be worthwhile. Most of what you might want to do with jMeter can probably be done in Fiddler itself, and if your goal is to use jMeter for everything except the initial capture, you can instead use the proxy recorder included in the jMeter product instead of Fiddler.